# Calling a function on the primary GLib.Application instance from a remote instance

Tags: glib, dbus, vala

I need to call the following function on the primary GLib.Application instance from a remote instance.

```
private void do_stuff (string[] args)
{
   ...
}
```

I assume I'll need to use DBus through `GLib.Application.get_dbus_connection ()` but don't have the slightest clue where to start.

Comment: You can't directly pass a file descriptor between processes. The operating system has no mechanism for dealing with that.

Comment: Did you read these links? 

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/DBusServerSample
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/DBusClientSamples